# Strange thoughts!

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, questions

The interesting part is that people can't have weird queries and if they have and post it most of the time the answer comes containing words "I am voting to close it because it's too trivial /too broad /too different" may be. Obvious queries do get lots of answers and up votes.And most of the time answer contains a link, that means it's a known query and known answer but if the question is not so known and answer is not so known  someone from the group obviously will vote to close it with a reason!!  Strange. And finally getting bored with stack exchange in less than 7 days. Obviously there are people who try to answer even it's a downvoted question or a trivial question but someone will be there to close it. I am new to this site and I am feeling very uneasy to be a part of one of the most famous sites with people carrying so many experiences,work, research and lots of degrees. I am a student, a very bad student with lots of questions. I know there are some guidelines to post a query and things like vote up, vote down and all. But ultimately!  What is the actual point of the site?  When I open stack exchange it says "expert answers to your questions". But If my question is too trivial and that doesn't really have a meaning then why is the question coming in my mind? I know probably after this post people will consider it madness and report it as flag and I don't know what not. But I thought it's good to be clear with all these.

Comment: It is good that you are getting a lot of questions in you mind. Being inquisitive and curious is a very good thing. However you should also learn to ask your question properly. Have a look at the [these tips](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question and also check out other FAQs in the help center.

Answer (score 4):

From the biology SE [tour](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour) page

> Biology Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for biology researchers, academics, and students. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about biology."

And

> Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.
>
> Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.

The questions you ask here should be well thought-out and related directly to biology. If your questions don't meet that criteria, they will be closed.